# Is it possible to track for users exporting data from Bigquery to Google Drive, local storage, or other destinations in the Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, information-schema

Can I accomplish this using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOB, or should I track it through the Log Explorer in GCP? I am aware that INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOB with job_type = "EXTRACT" can only track exports of query results to Google Drive.

What I aim to do is track whether users are exporting data from BigQuery to any destination.

Comment: Do you want to track or to deny ?

Comment: I want to track it, and if possible, I also want to track the size of the data being exported @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: I don't know if you can, but it's sure it's useless. From BigQuery perspective a query is an API call. Then the consumption of the result is not the concern of BigQuery. If you track the UI action, what about the APIs action? If a user use directly the API, save locally the data and resell them on the black market, your previous monitoring system is useless! You can prevent exfiltration with VPC SC and create a safe perimeter around your data (but it's boring to manage...)

Comment: then can an alert policy be set up in BigQuery to notify whenever someone tries to export data? @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: What's an export? It's simply a query that you save in a file and that you use out of BigQuery. That means you need to have an alert for each query in BigQuery. It's a great question, a great concern, but without obvious answer....

Comment: What if we deny it? How can we deny or prohibit users from exporting data? @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: If a user as access to the data, and if you don't set a VPC SC perimeter, you can't prevent the storage somewhere.